# how to show that $w = x\,dy$ isn't exact?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

if I choose to integrate it over the square of vertices $(0,0),\,(0,1),\,(1,0),\,(1,1)$

then $\int_\text{square} w = \int_{0}^{1} t\,dt = \frac 12 \neq 0 $

so since the integral over a closed curve isn't zero it's not exact, right ?

is my way of evaluating the integral correct ?

Comment: Quick proof:
Exact => Closed, but $d(xdy) = dx\wedge dy = \mathrm{vol}_{\mathbb{R}^2} \neq 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that integrating over the sides of a square (or any other closed path) and getting a non-zero answer would show the form is not exact.

But that is not what you did in this integral. Instead of integrating over the sides of the square. You have integrated along a diagonal of the square. This is not a closed path, so it proves nothing.

To integrate the path you intended, you need to parameterize each of the 4 sides: from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$, then from $(0,1)$ to $(1,1)$, then from $(1,1)$ to $(1, 0)$, then from $(1,0)$ to $(0,0)$. Then you will have a closed path.

Comment: I think I know my mistake I paramterized wrong so I think I'll have to parametrize each line of the square separately to avoid any type of confusion

Comment: also along the horizontal sides, the integral is zero because of the $dy$, right ? so I only need to parameterize twice ?

Comment: Yes. I was just adding a line (as you can see) explaining that when you commented. I'm glad the extra explanation wasn't actually needed.

Comment: Yes, when $y$ is constant, the integrations will be $0$, so only the vertical sides will give a non-zero contribution.